# Not authorized to execute any sonarqube analysis with sonarqube scanner on Travis CI

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I recently started using Travis CI and sonarqube in an open source project and have run into a problem with sonarqube-scanner.

My Travis CI page can be seen here: https://travis-ci.org/uglyoldbob/decompiler

My sonarqube page can be seen here: https://sonarqube.com/overview?id=uglyoldbob_decompiler

I'm running sonarqube-scanner on Travis CI it suddenly stopped working with the following error:

```
"ERROR: You're not authorized to execute any SonarQube analysis. Please contact your SonarQube administrator."
```

I am using a token generated on sonarqube and have added it to the environment variables of Travis CI. I generated a new token when I noticed the problem and updated the environment variable with Travis but it did not change anything.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In General:** You need to pass a user token from an account with analysis permissions in your analysis parameters. Use the `sonar.login` property to do it.

**Specifically:** I see from your travis log that you *are* passing what looks like a user token in the sonar.login property. *However* you are passing it to `sonar.host.url=http://nemo.sonarqube.org`. You need to change this to `https://sonarqube.com`

Comment: Ah, that was the solution. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

with mvn I had to pass to sonarcloud.io the parameter `-Dsonar.branch=master`

all command goes something like this:

```
mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent package sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io -Dsonar.organization={ORG_KEY} -Dsonar.login={GENERATED_KEY_ON_SONARCLOUD_SECURITY} -Dsonar.branch={BRANCH_NAME}
```

this fixed the following error:

> You're only authorized to execute a local (preview) SonarQube analysis without pushing the results to the SonarQube server. Please contact your SonarQube administrator.

remember adding the analysis permission on the sonarcloud admin console.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it was a permission issue.
Administration >> Security >> Global permission
[image]

Answer (score 2):

"Chances are that the SonarCloud project key inferred from your Gradle configuration is already used by someone else" (Fabrice Bellingard at https://community.sonarsource.com/t/unauthorized-exception-on-first-sonarqube-analysis/333/2)

Choose a fix:

```
 -Dsonar.projectKey=$my_own_project_key
```

Or via `build.gradle`:

```groovy
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.projectKey', '$my_own_project_key'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue, caused by proxy configuration. Solved by adding the sonar server ip in nonProxyHost config in settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was entering a wrong key for the project

Answer (score -1):

In my case, it was a firewall rule that was blocking the analysis file to upload, but this message is so generic it can be anything :(.