# Authorization error when using Sonarcloud on Travis CI

Tags: sonarqube, travis-ci, sonarcloud

I am trying to use SonarCloud with Travis-CI and getting the following error:

> * What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
>
> You're only authorized to execute a local (preview) SonarQube analysis without pushing the results to the SonarQube server. Please contact your SonarQube administrator.

[Here](https://github.com/deshetti/test-travis) is the project on Github that I am trying to setup CI using Travis.

[Here](https://travis-ci.org/deshetti/test-travis/builds/417462726) is the link for the Travis build that is failing executing the SonarQube step.

[Here](https://travis-ci.org/deshetti/test-travis/jobs/417474394/config) is the Travis config file

[Here](https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=9d2401997a7368e6f351d50d7d99bbf1fae84624) is the link for the Sonarcloud project.

On Travis I added the added the Env variable SONAR_TOKEN to 9d2401997a7368e6f351d50d7d99bbf1fae84624 and I see that it is picked up fine on the Travis Job Log.

I am very new to both Travis and Sonarqube, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shashi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375162/not-authorized-to-execute-any-sonarqube-analysis-with-sonarqube-scanner-on-travi) SO question

Comment: The [onboarding tutorial](https://sonarcloud.io/onboarding) is written for setting up analysis via Travis IIRC. You might try stepping through it.

Comment: @JeroenHeier While the error message is the same, but the issue and solution mentioned in the response doesn't seem like the reason for mine. I already setup my Travis file like mentioned in the response: "./gradlew sonarqube --no-daemon -Dsonar.organization=deshetti-github -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN"

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Thanks for the response. The link you mentioned in your comment doesn't take me to any tutorial. Instead it just takes me directly to creating another new token. Can you please check the link once again.

Answer (score 0):

You need not set **SONAR_TOKEN**. If you are getting authorization error, because of a bad encrypted token.

The problem is with the travis encryption.

**Correct encryption syntax:**

`travis encrypt 309473973909Z09R830 -r my-org/my-repo`

No variable name, no quote.

If you are running travis encrypt inside your repo directory you can just use

`travis encrypt 309473973909Z09R830`

Kindly replace you token for`309473973909Z09R830`

This token can be used in place of `secret` as specified in the official travis [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/sonarcloud/).